# Vars always does not save inswift

Tags: swift, xcode, variables

I am trying to create a var of string with custom address.
I am new at Swift but every time I set the address in `geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation` block the value isn't saved!

```
var address:String = ""
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.passenger1Location!) { (placemark, error) in
    if error != nil {
        //showing error alert
        return
    }
    if let place = placemark?[0] {
        address = place.name!
    }

}

print(address)
```

and then when I print the `self.address` its lets me `""` but if I put the print in the block of commands (`if let place = placemark?[0]`) it will print for me the current address.
How can I change the address value also outside of the block?